# How to pass on a start value to input?

Tags: reactjs

Here it is:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" onChange={this.handleInputChangeEdit}/>
```

When I try to set start value into input (value ={...}) it becomes blocked and it's impossible to change string. How to evade this?

Comment: Can you add this function code : this.handleInputChangeEdit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **defaultValue** instead of **value** as attribute for input as mentioned on react documentation (for uncontrolled components). There are multiple ways to effect the same change but this seems to be the simplest based on what you were already trying to do.

https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: Thanks! It fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

To give the input a default value while still being able to update it, you should connect it to your component-state.

Simply put, any time you type something, you trigger your `handleInputChangeEdit` function. It takes the text you enter and updates the `firstname` field in `state`. That value gets passed back down to the input for display.

```
class App extends React.Component{
   state = {
     firstname: "This is the default text"
   }

   handleInputChangeEdit = (event) => {
      this.setState({
         [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      })
   }

   render(){
     return(
        <input
          value={this.state.firstname}
          type="text" 
          name="firstname" 
          onChange={this.handleInputChangeEdit}
        />
     )
   }
}
```

The initial/default value will be whatever you had in the `state` object and now you are free to update the input-text which continues this pattern.